# Enable ZFS ZED Email Notifications on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, email, notification, zfs

As ZFS is now officially supported in Ubuntu 16.04, I would like to enable email notifications for my ZFS pool. Below are the steps I have taken so far, however I am now currently stuck:

- Installed msmtp and set it up to work with an external gmail account successfully.
- Uncommented and configured /etc/zfs/zed.d/zed.rc
- Set ZED_NOTIFY_VERBOSE=1
- Ran zpool scrub expecting to receive a notification of the clean scrub, no email is sent

This is the only post that I can find relating to ZFS/ZED configuration, however I was unable to get it to work:
http://louwrentius.com/the-zfs-event-daemon-on-linux.html

---

Update:
Both responses from Mumblepins and Martin led to the fix. Below are the full steps needed to get this to work:

- Install msmtp and set it up to work with an external email account (gmail or whatever)
- Install s-nail and msmtp-mta packages to map msmtp to the mail command
- Uncomment and configure /etc/zfs/zed.d/zed.rc (keeping ZED_EMAIL_PROG="mail")
- systemctl enable zed

Comment: Did you try sending the mail to a non-gmail account?  Also, what is the "from:" address ZED uses?  This might be Google's spamfilter not liking that mail...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found your post when trying to set it up, what I did to make it work is:

1. Uncommented and configured `/etc/zfs/zed.d/zed.rc`
2. Set ZED_NOTIFY_VERBOSE=1 in the file  `/etc/zfs/zed.d/zed.rc`
3. enable the zed daemon:

   > systemctl enable zed

Ran a scrub and it works!

Note that if the service is already running, you get the error:

> Failed to enable unit: Refusing to operate on linked unit file zed.service.

In that case, just restart it:

> systemctl restart zed

Comment: This does not work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you test whether plain sending works? For example by executing `echo "Test Email from the new server" | mail -s "Test Subject" root`

Comment: Yeah, that works. And I got ZED working too. Can't remember what I did differently in the end, though. I think it was a bug in ZOL that I had to patch.

Comment: @lindhe Did you confirm that you can send mail?

Answer (score 3):

The default zed.rc file uses the command line syntax of the `mail` client, which allows for a subject line in the command line.  `msmtp` only has the subject in the STDIN.  So if you're using a command line in zed.rc of msmtp, you'll need to remove the `-s subject` part of the command.  Otherwise, if msmtp-mta is installed, you can use `mail` as the client in zed.rc and mail will use msmtp

Comment: I can not get this to work. Using local postfix from installing `mailutils` works perfect with zed. So does `echo 'Message body' | mail -s 'A subject' me@example.com` when I've installed `msmtp` and `msmtp-mta`. But even with `msmtp-mta` installed, zed will not send me mail. Any suggestions?